# Vertical Align form-group bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to get my button align the middle vertically but isn't working my code, here is my code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 pull-right col-btn">
    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-purple">
            Calculate
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.col-btn .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` depending on what?

Comment: `vertical-align` aligns elements to each other...it doesn't vertically align contents.

Comment: @NenadVracar i want to aling my button inside of his column, for example the column have 400px of height, and i wish my button to be in the middle vertically.

Answer (score 3):

Ok try this. I think it will work with boostrap https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/135/

**CSS**

```
.col-btn {
    height:400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}

.col-btn .form-group {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Align vertical and horizontal

This is for horizontal alignment, if you dont want, remove.

```
width: 100px;  
margin: 0 auto;
```

```css
.col-btn .form-group {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 pull-right col-btn">
                    <div class="form-group text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-purple">
                            Calculate
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```